# Assistance routing a footprint

Tags: pcb-design, footprint, routing

I'm attempting to learn PCB design. Mostly super basic stuff to replace the rats nest of wires between my Arduino modules.

Anyway I'm using the following component in a project and can't quite figure out how I'm expected to route to some of its pads.

https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/Xunpu-TYPEC_951ARP24/C2856663

https://lcsc.com/product-detail/USB-Connectors_XUNPU-XUNPU-TYPEC-951-ARP24_C2856663.html

Its a JLCPCB provided part so they can assemble it for me, the soldering is far beyond my ability.

Its a surface mounted USB-c Male connector. There are edge cuts defined in its foot print to allow for the male part of the connector, otherwise it would intersect the PCB.

The following image is its footprint imported into KiCad (using the following [tool](https://github.com/TousstNicolas/JLC2KiCad_lib) ), the white line is the edge cut defined by the footprint.

[image]

I'm struggling with how one is expected to route traces to the second row of pads (B1 - B12)?

There doesn't seem to be enough space between the defined edge and the pads for traces. Not enough space in-between the pads for vias and my understanding is its bad practice to put vias under the pads themselves.

I'm a little lost how I'm expected to route to these pads. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ya, via-in-pad. You can either risk it without special precautions (assembly yield may be poor -- how many of those pads do you *need* connected?), order with precautions (usually plugged vias, adds cost), or choose a different part.

Comment: @TimWilliams i only need to make use of 2 pads in this instance, but it got me thinking more generally there will be projects using them all and was stumped how they were expecting it to be used. I didn't know `via-in-pad` was a term, ill look that up. It may be my only option.

Comment: via-in-pad is typically very expensive for small runs just fyi. Your much better off going to a different component, or moving to smaller vias.

Comment: Ok thanks. All others I found were edge fit. I assume for this reason. Tried to use this one to save on the hand assembly fee that edge fit would incur. However sounds like the vias would negate this, thanks for the advice all.

Comment: You absolutely should not be using a connector that hangs off the PC board to such an extent. It can stick out a little bit to go through an enclosure if you have a box in mind. If this is a free-standing (not enclosed) board, then the USB-C connector should only protrude a tiny bit. 1-2mm is plenty.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica but this is a male connector, not female. Surly it has to hang of enough for the connector to fully engage with its female counterpart?